# Selecting a row based on a field value on the 1st of the month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below table I want to select a row where "Days" = 1 but the account should have Days = 0 on the 1st of the month.

```
Account| Date | Days
-------|------|-----
A | 1/3/2015 | 0
A | 5/3/2015 | 1
A | 9/3/2015 | 10
B | 1/3/2015 | 30
B | 3/3/2015 | 1
B | 6/3/2015 | 12
```

The result should be 2nd row

```
A        5/3/2015   1
```

On the 1st A has 0 days but B has 30 days hence I want only account A

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I use MS SQL server

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is for ORACLE, but take a look. Idea is:

> SELECT *
>     FROM ACCOUNTS
>    WHERE     DAYS = 1
>          AND ACC IN (SELECT ACCOUNT
>                        FROM ACCOUNTS
>                       WHERE ACC_DATE = TRUNC (ACC_DATE, 'MONTH') AND DAYS = 0)

Try to convert to MSSQL and run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using window function `max` with `case` to find out if there is a row with day = 1 and Days = 0 and if there is, return second row using `row_number` in the order of increasing date for that account in that month.

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        max(case when day(date) = 1 and Days = 0 then 1 end) 
            over (partition by Account, month(Date), year(Date)) flag,
        row_number() over (
            partition by Account, month(Date), year(Date)
            order by Date
            ) rn
    from your_table t
) t where flag = 1 and rn = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT account, date, days
FROM table_name t
WHERE days = 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM table_name
            WHERE account = t.account 
                AND date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, t.date), 0)  
                --cast(date As Date) = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, t.date), 0)
                AND days = 0);
```